How to navigate from Blazor to external page in the same domain
Let's say we have a simple Blazor WebAssembly app with the following pages
/index
/counter
/fetchdata

This app is hosted within an MVC app that has the following routes
/login
/logout

The problem is when trying to navigate to /logout from the Blazor app, it catches the route and show the known page

Sorry, there's nothing at this address

Using the following code to navigate to /login page
_navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login", forceLoad = true);

My question: is there any way to escape from Blazor service worker for not-found routes, Or just bypass the navigation to the browser for specific route.
Thanks in advance

It would be a good idea to show what particular methods you've tried for initiating the navigation.

@Logarr I updated the question adding what I have tried, Thanks.

You'll have to treat it as if it's an external site, because from Blazor's perspective it is.
Including the entire URL instead of a relative path should be sufficient.
_navigationManager.NavigateTo("https://<YourSiteHere>/login", forceLoad = true);

I don't think the forceLoad is required for it at that point.
